# Changing the way the Radio list is rendered in the WFM when source is given

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have been looking for a solution for the following:
We have a webform on which we want to give a selection of items from a specified sitecore folder. The children of this folder have to be selectable on the form, but I want to override the way they are presented in the Radio List. Now the items are presented using the Item's name, but I want to have a Field of the item to be presented as Drop List item name. I have been looking something to override to implement this functionality but did not succeed. The WFM module is rather old ("2.0.0 rev. 091120") and does not have the option to select a field to present in the list (it just takes the item's name). Where can I implement the described behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you de-compile `Sitecore.Forms.Custom.dll` you can get to the class for the radio list: `Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.RadioList`. I don't know exactly where, but I suspect you can override a method to initialize the item collection. It might either be in this class or a base class.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for helping. I have been looking into that part using a decompiler, but it's derived from a base class and I can't find how to override the way this List is Initialized. Is there any chance you can be more specific? Cheers!